# How can I show all file types contained in a directory?

Tags: command-line

Is there any command which tells me in the specific directory which types of files exist?

I can find out the file type by using a command like `od -c myfile | less`.

But I don't know how to do it for all files in a directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although `od -c` will indeed show the contents of a file, it is not a good way to get its file type. While some files will contain a header with the file type, not all will. A better way is the command `file`:

```
$ echo "hello" > foo.txt
$ file foo.txt
foo.txt: ASCII text
```

So, to get a list of all file types in a directory, you can do:

```
for file in dir/*; do file "$file" | cut -d: -f 2; done | sort -u
```

#### Example output:

```
 PNG image data, 1500 x 500, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
 ASCII text
 directory
 GIF image data, version 89a, 22 x 22
 ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=becf821e4d814fdb69306d0b3f686eb06992f5e5, stripped
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in dir/*; do ... done;` : iterate through everything in `dir` (`dir` is just an example, you should change this to the name of the actual directory you want to search through), saving each item in turn as `$file`
- `file "$file"` :  run `file` on each of the items found.
- `cut -d: -f 2` : print only the second field (fields defined by `:`)
- `sed 's/^ //; s/ +/ /g'` : remove spaces from the beginning of the line and convert consecutive spaces into a single space.
- `sort -u` : remove duplicate file types

Comment: thanks, But I exactly copy and past "for file in dir/*; do file "$file" | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -u; done" in my terminal and I got " ERROR"

Comment: @alex first of all, please always mention the exact error you get, saying that you got "ERROR" is not very useful. In any case, the error is probably because you have no directory named `dir/`, that was just an example name, you will need to change that to the name of a real directory: `for file in /home/alex/*; do ... done` for example.

Comment: thanks, If you did my wrong work(...I thought dir is command like ls not directory -sorry- also I think better to edit your answer)You just see "ERROR" and nothing else.

Comment: nice job, thnaks, but I saw for example four line "Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains" or more than one"ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
". I am not sure about "remove duplicate".

Comment: @alex fair enough, answer edited. You should not be getting any duplicates. The `sort -u` will remove them, the lines must be different (they might also have a different number of spaces, that makes them non-identical).

Comment: this is my outputreza@reza-N43JM:~$ for file in /home/reza/* ; do file "$file" | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -u; done
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
 XML document text
 XML document text
 Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains

Comment: @alex that's because I'm an idiot. Try the edited answer, the `sort -u` needs to be outside the loop, otherwise it only ever sees a single line at a time.

Comment: Thanks,I try the last one. I wish to become such an idiot

Comment: You can cut the `cut` with `file`'s `-b` option, and give `file` the whole list: `file -b dir/* | sort -u` – I think this comment section could use a cleanup. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do something like this -

```
find . -type f -exec file {}  \;
```

That will search from the current path, for files (e.g. no directories) and then execute the `file` command on each file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls | xargs file -b | sort | uniq
```

How it works:

**ls**: list directory contents

**file -b**: determine file type; do not prepend filenames to output lines

**sort**: sort lines

**uniq**: omit repeated lines

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: You could use `file -b *` instead of `ls | xargs file -b`, to avoid parsing `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

```
find . -type f | awk -F. '!a[$NF]++{print $NF}'
```