# How do I display filetype with ls?

Tags: command-line, ls

I am ignorant as to whether `ls` is capable of displaying a filetype column.

Doing a quick online search and searching the `man` did not reveal such a capability. Is it capable of doing this?

Clarification: This is especially helpful if files do not have an extension.

**Update**

As of 2018-04-28 the answers have been quite interesting however they did not provide what I was looking for. More specifically,

- `file` does give the actual filetypes but it doesn't integrate well with `ls`. Specifically, I use `ls -lhtrpG --group-directories-first --color=always`
- `ls -F` is an `ls` solution however it provides symbols not a column of actual filetypes.

For this reason I have not marked any of the answers as the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Related: [How can I show all file types contained in a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/442474/507051)

Comment: related info: for human readable: `ls -lahtrpF --group-directories-first --color=always /dev` or `ls -lsahG /dev` , and for program readable `ls -lsa /dev` . see `man ls` documentation for details.

Answer (score 33):

I think the best way to display a file type is using this command:

```
file <filename>
```

If you want to list the types of all files in a directory, just use:

```
file *
```

[image: <code>file *</code> sample from my computer]

For more details about the arguments, see:

```
man file
```

Comment: While this answer doesnt directly respond to the OP's question, it shows the correct way of finding the mime type of a file and should be marked as the correct answer. To get the `mime type` only, use: `file --mime-type filename`.

Comment: @PedroLobito I think the [closely related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/442474/507051) covers `file` quite well, but this question is different.

Comment: I vote this answer up given that you were the first to give a `file` answer. As I replied to the others this doesn't suffice (it needs to be integrated with ls) so I keep it at a vote up. Thank you.

Comment: file * is the best answer

Comment: `file --mime /dev/*` for list mimes in directory /dev instead of current

Answer (score 19):

`file` is definitely the right choice to get the file type information you want. To combine its output with that of `ls` I suggest to use `find`:

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls -exec file -b {} \;
```

This finds every file in the current directory and prints the output of `ls -dils` as well as the output of `file -b` for it, each on an own line. Example output:

```
  2757145      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 dessert dessert      914 Apr 26 14:02 ./some.html
HTML document, ASCII text
  2757135      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 dessert dessert      201 Apr 13 15:26 ./a_text_file
UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

But, as you don't want a filetype *line* but rather a filetype *column*, here's a way to get rid of the newline character between the lines:

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "ls -l {} | tr '\n' '\t'; file -b {}" \;
```

Sample output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 914 Apr 26 14:02 ./some.html    HTML document, ASCII text
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 201 Apr 13 15:26 ./a_text_file  UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

That new column is quite long, so let's cut everything from the first comma:

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "ls -l {} | tr '\n' '\t'; file -b {} | cut -d, -f1" \;
```

The output of that looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 914 Apr 26 14:02 ./some.html    HTML document
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 201 Apr 13 15:26 ./a_text_file  UTF-8 Unicode text
```

This is not quite handy, so how about an `alias`? With the following line in your `~/.bash_aliases` file you just need to run `lsf` to get the above output for the current directory.

```bsh
alias lsf='find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "ls -l {} | tr '"'\n'"' '"'\t'"'; file -b {} | cut -d, -f1" \;'
```

Comment: If you use a function instead of an alias, that will be less of a quoting hell, and if you use `paste` or `column`, you could get better alignment: `lsf () { find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'column <(ls -l "$@") <(file -b "$@" | cut -d, -f1)' _ {} + ; }` The alignment issue is not evident in the answer because of the similar sizes and dates. (This will also be slightly faster, since the commands will be invoked fewer times instead of once per file.)

Comment: @muru Thanks for the many good suggestions! Does this `column` aproach work for you? It just prints the output of `ls -l` for every file followed by `file`'s output for every file for me, as if the shell would just do `ls -l "$@"; file -b "$@" | cut -d, -f1`…

Comment: It does. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KjPthXPDPb/ - the top part is from the alias and the bottom part is the  function, both run from `/etc`.

Comment: I think I see the problem - if `column`'s output is not to the terminal, you need to specify the column count or it will output the files one after the other; so `column -c "$COLUMNS" ...` should work in either case.

Comment: You are launching (at least?) 5 processes for each file, so this is probably going to be slow when there are lots of files in a directory…

Comment: As @Janc mentioned this would be slow. However I vote it up for your effort and for being the answer being most relevant to what I was searching for (actual filetypes).

Comment: @JanC @user10853 How slow is it really? For the 2803 files in my `/usr/bin` directory it takes 6.316s, that's 2,25 ms/file. I agree that's not instantaneous, but considering the real world use of a command like that I think it's by far fast enough to use – even more if you use muru's version.

Answer (score 11):

For clarity, I'm going to point out that you can see the [file type](https://askubuntu.com/tags/files/info) in a basic sense with `ls`, using the `-F` flag (classify) which appends a symbol to the filename depending on its type:

```
‘-F’
‘--classify’
‘--indicator-style=classify’
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’.  The file
     type indicators are ‘/’ for directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links,
     ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets, ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.
```

You can see that information slightly less cryptically displayed in the first letter of the output of `ls -l`, though. [wjandrea's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028541/527764) describes this in more detail.

But I don't think this is what you mean by file type. The `ls` command does not look inside regular files - only at directory listings (which store filenames) and inodes (which store metadata, including the "type" in the sense mentioned earlier).

So, the `ls` command cannot show the file type in the sense of whether it is a JPG image or a binary file or a text file or a LibreOffice document of some kind, because it does not have that information.

For that, as [singrium's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028508/527764) points out, you need the `file` command, which looks at the first 50-100kB or so of files' contents to determine their type.

Answer (score 10):

One form of filetype is whether a file is a regular file, directory, device, symlink, etc. `ls` can show this using options `-l` or `-F`.

- Option `-l` will show the filetype as a single character at the start of a listing, e.g:

  ```
  $ ls -l
  drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec 11 00:18 DIR
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Dec 11 00:18 FILE
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    4 Dec 11 00:19 LINK -> FILE
  ```

  Where `-` is a regular file, `d` is a directory, and `l` is a symlink.
- Option `-F` will show the filetype as a suffix, e.g:

  ```
  $ ls -F
  DIR/ FILE LINK@
  ```

  Where no suffix is a regular file, `/` is a directory, and `@` is a symlink.

More info on these is available in [`info coreutils 'ls invocation'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html), summed up here:

For [`-l`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html):

```
‘-’ regular file
‘b’ block special file
‘c’ character special file
‘C’ high performance (“contiguous data”) file
‘d’ directory
‘D’ door (Solaris 2.5 and up)
‘l’ symbolic link
‘M’ off-line (“migrated”) file (Cray DMF)
‘n’ network special file (HP-UX)
‘p’ FIFO (named pipe)
‘P’ port (Solaris 10 and up)
‘s’ socket
‘?’ some other file type
```

For [`-F`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html):

```
nothing for regular files
‘*’ regular files that are executable
‘/’ directories
‘@’ symbolic links
‘|’ FIFOs
‘=’ sockets
‘>’ doors
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way using paste to merge two output of ls and file command

```
paste <(ls -dl *) <(file * | cut -d: -f2)
```